# I added javascript validations to my login control and it is though errors are present

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I added javascript validations to my login control and it is though errors are present my code inside **button_click** is executed. How to stop execution in **button_click** untill validations become null.

Answer (score 2):

hello friend you can use this type of javascript code to validate your control and stop executed your code behind code using javascript validation

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ClientScript() {
            //validate your text box
            //if validate return true
            //else return false
            return true;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="qa" 
            Text="Test Validation" OnClientClick="return ClientScript();" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here i have putted simply one textbox and button and on button Onclientclick called one javascript function which will validate your text box and return true or false based on validation. if you return true from your javascript function then it will execute your button1_click event other wise it will simple return.

you can modified this code and make appropriate to use in your design.

Comment: thank you bro.than you very much